# How to treat hierachy of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem which can roughly be described as follows: I have a (finite dimensional) vector space $V$ and (invertible) matrices $A_n:V^{\otimes n} \to V^{\otimes n}$ and a different set of matrices $B_n:V^{\otimes n+1} \to V^{\otimes n}$, both for $n = 1,2,\ldots$. I would like to solve the following hierachy of linear equations:
$$A_n x_n = B_n x_{n+1},$$
where $x_n \in V^{\otimes n}$. The $A_n$'s and $B_n$'s are of course different matrices, but still they have a similar structure (sorry, I know this is not very formal, see the example below to see what I mean).

Of course I could create many solutions by starting with an arbitrary $x_1$ and then choosing one of the possible solutions $x_2$ so that $A_1 x_1 = B_1 x_2$, then so choosing $x_3$ and so one. But this is not what I would like to do: I would rather start with an $x_N$ for a very large $N$ and then compute all the $x_n$ down to $x_1$ from it. My intuition tells me that, because the $A_n$'s and $B_n$'s are similar, the $x_n$'s for small $n$ should also be similar. In some sense I expect the $x_n$ to run to something like a 'fixed point' of the system.

As a simple example, let us choose $V = R^d$ and set $A_n = id$. Fix some vector $a \in V$. The $B_n$ are defined as follows:
$$B_n: v_1\otimes v_2 \otimes \ldots \otimes v_{n+1} \mapsto (a\cdot v_1) v_2 \otimes \ldots \otimes v_{n+1} + (a\cdot v_2) v_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes v_{n+1}+\ldots + (a\cdot v_{n+1}) v_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes v_n,$$ and then extended onto all other vectors by taking linear combinations. Here the $a\cdot v$ represents the usual dot product of two vectors. If we fix a vector $v$, then $x_n = v\otimes v \ldots \otimes v$ clearly is a solution (up to a prefactor) to the hierachy. Also these vectors are somehow self similar. Because of that, I expect that if we start with a random vector $x_N$ for a very large $N$, the $x_n$ will be close to such a vector $x_n = v^{\otimes n}$, for some $v$.

Is there any theory about problems like these? Is my intuition correct or not? In either case, do you know any strategies to solve problems like these?

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful information, but your $B_n$ can be expressed as an $n$-fold [Kronecker sum](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerSum.html).